# Why I have "Not found" /admin in symfony easyAdminBundle 4 (php)

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, php-8.1, symfony6

I can't open /admin page after installing easyAdminBundle in symfony app.

I do:
 `symfony composer req "admin:^4"`
then
`symfony console make:admin:dashboard`

This line generate this code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Dashboard;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\MenuItem;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractDashboardController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    #[Route('/admin', name: 'admin')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return parent::index();

        // Option 1. You can make your dashboard redirect to some common page of your backend
        //
        // $adminUrlGenerator = $this->container->get(AdminUrlGenerator::class);
        // return $this->redirect($adminUrlGenerator->setController(OneOfYourCrudController::class)->generateUrl());

        // Option 2. You can make your dashboard redirect to different pages depending on the user
        //
        // if ('jane' === $this->getUser()->getUsername()) {
        //     return $this->redirect('...');
        // }

        // Option 3. You can render some custom template to display a proper dashboard with widgets, etc.
        // (tip: it's easier if your template extends from @EasyAdmin/page/content.html.twig)
        //
        // return $this->render('some/path/my-dashboard.html.twig');
    }

    public function configureDashboard(): Dashboard
    {
        return Dashboard::new()
            ->setTitle('Symfony App');
    }

    public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
    {
        yield MenuItem::linkToDashboard('Dashboard', 'fa fa-home');
        // yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('The Label', 'fas fa-list', EntityClass::class);
    }
}
```

But when I try to open /admin page I get this:
"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server."

This lines doesn't help:

```
symfony console cache:clear

symfony composer dump-autoload

rm -rf var/cache/*
```

I want to see the start page at easyAdminBundle like in symfony documentation. Why I can't get this?

Comment: Does the command `symfony console debug:router` show you `/admin` route?

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen , yes

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a fresh project.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by changing the route for `DashboardController::index` from `'/admin'` to `'/admin/d'` then going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/d`

```php
class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
  #[Route('/admin/d', name: 'admin')]
  public function index(): Response
  {
    return parent::index();
  }
  /* ... */
}
```